# Value from input in quotes javascript

Tags: javascript, input, quotes

If I have an code like this, with quotes and authors, how can I get two `input type="text"` boxes where I can write for example two names and then display the name into the quotes in place of  "(random user)"?

```
//store the quotations in arrays
quotes = [];

authors = [];

quotes[0] = "(randomuser) example (randomuser) example?";

authors[0] = "Authors!";

quotes[1] = "(random user) example (random user) example?";

authors[1] = "Authors!";

//calculate a random index
index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

//display the quotation

document.write("<DL>\n");

document.write("<DT>" + "\"" + quotes[index] + "\"\n");

document.write("<DD>" + " " + authors[index] + "\n");

document.write("</DL>\n");

//done
```

Comment: avoid using `document.write` as much as possible

Comment: is spoon feeding allowed ?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin : Since the OP is learning `JS` , I think it is allowed :) but I could be wrong here

Comment: @harsha can u write some fast example? :)

Comment: You want to replace `(randomuser)` inside the string with a name from the `authors` array?

Comment: no i want to replace the (random user) with value from input box :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to replace the (randomuser) in the quotes array with strings that you get from a couple of `<input>` tags.  In that case, you could get the contents of those inputs like so:

```
var user1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
var user2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
```

Now, you could substitute "(randomuser1)" and "(randomuser2)" for those inputted values using `String.replace()`, like so:

```
//Sub in the usernames
var newquote = quotes[0].replace("(randomuser1)", user1); //quotes[0] can of course be any index
newquote = newquote.replace("(randomuser2)", user2);
```

And then you can display `newquote`.  Keep in mind that you should avoid `document.write()`.  Instead, you could make a display div on your page and then put the quote into that, like this:

```
var quotediv = document.getElementById("quoteDiv"); //get the div (or any other element) that you want to display the quote in
quotediv.innerHTML = newquote; //display your quote in the div.
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mvp9U/)

**EDIT**:

To select a quote randomly from a larger list, you would change `quotes[0]` to something like `quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)]`.  To add more users, you would add more inputs and more replace statements.  Example:

```
//Sub in the usernames
var ind = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length); //select random quote
var newquote = quotes[ind].replace("(randomuser1)", user1);
newquote = newquote.replace("(randomuser2)", user2);
newquote = newquote.replace("(randomuser3)", user3);
newquote = newquote.replace("(randomuser4)", user4);
newquote = newquote.replace("(randomuser5)", user5);
```

That could be simplified into a for loop for a larger number of users, but I will leave you to figure that out.

Comment: if i have an list with lets say 100 quotes and 5 users , how can i make that ?:) thanks for your answer!!

Comment: Edited the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks !!! 
http://jsfiddle.net/mvp9U/1/

why is it always the second quote that displays in the div ? ;o

Comment: You were defining the array twice instead of defining it with two elements.  Here is [a fixed example](http://jsfiddle.net/mvp9U/2/), see line 1.